# can't access /dev/sda3 from non-root user

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, permission-denied, user-permissions

unable to access a partition MyMedia (/Dev/sda3) on Ubuntu 14.04 which I've dual booted alongside windows-7.
I've kept this partition for Ubuntu related installation and downloads.

```
hdpusr@akshay-300E4Z-300E5Z-300E7Z:/media/akshay$ ls -l
total 52
drwx------ 1 akshay akshay 24576 Apr  9 10:51 Movies
drwx------ 1 akshay akshay 12288 Apr 23 12:31 MyMedia
drwx------ 1 akshay akshay 16384 Apr  7 15:54 Windows


hdpusr@akshay-300E4Z-300E5Z-300E7Z:/media/akshay$ cd MyMedia
bash: cd: MyMedia: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added this line in *fstab* and now i am able to access the partition 
/dev/sda3 (MyMedia)
->

```
UUID=84DA4105DA40F548   /media/akshay/MyMedia   ntfs    auto,rw,user,exec   00
```